# How do you use selenium web-driver for a website built under SilverLight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to do this? I'm not able to get any element from the site.

Comment: do what? did you forget to paste code?

Comment: Silverlight does not produce any "elements" in the sense of HTML elements.

Comment: @HighCore, does it mean I'm not able to scrape the site using Selenium?

Answer (score 1):

Look at using [Silvernium](https://code.google.com/p/silverlight-selenium/).

In order for Silvernium to be effective though, the Silverlight code needs to be modified.

The methods you want to use with Selenium must have the "Scriptable" attribute set, so that Selenium can make JavaScript calls to them.

From their [docs](https://code.google.com/p/silverlight-selenium/#Selenium_RC_/_Silverlight_Integration):

```
[Scriptable]
public void NewGame(int players)
{...}
```